# Multiple if are not working in python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code:

```
Split = Message.Body.split()
split = Split

if 'a' or 'b' or 'b' in split:
    time.sleep(2)
    print '1'
elif 'c' or 'd' in split:
    time.sleep(2)
    print '2'
elif 'e' or 'f' in split:
    time.sleep(2)
    print '3'
else:
    time.sleep(2)
    print '4'
```

I have used split to separate the words from my message and I want if a certain message is received to print a certain word, but now it only prints 1 regardless of the input.

Comment: What do you think 'a' converted to a Boolean would be? The 'or' isn't doing what you think

Comment: No, the 'a' wont be converted to boolean because I think `if 'a' or 'b' or 'b' in split:` is the same as this `if  'a' in split or 'b' in split or 'b' in split`

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Originally I wanted to write something like this but it is not possible `if(split == "a" || spit == "b" || split == "c")` I believe that because I read it on a website but now that I think about it, it does not make sense.

Comment: @worer: try `print(split)` and you'll understand why `split == "a"` or similar won't work. Also, `||` is not Python! ;)

Comment: Yeah I know it is not :), thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
>>> 'a' or 'b' or 'b'
'a'
```

This is the solution:

```
if 'a' in split or 'b' in split:
```

Or, if you have many letters to check:

```
if any(x in split for x in 'ab'):
```

works better for this case:

```
if any(x in split for x in 'abcdefg'):
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of inserting the correct `if` statement. Please remove it if it's not what you want

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks. :) I was still typing.

Comment: @worer note that you need to fix all three of your if/elif statements with the above advice to correct your script.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the stupid post

Answer (score 0):

An arguably more pythonic solution, especially for more cases:

```
cases = [('ab', 1), ('cd', 2), ('ef', 3)]

for key, value in cases:
    if any(x in split for x in key):
        time.sleep(2)
        print(value)
        break
else:
    time.sleep(2)
    print(4)
```